# Accessing union members after assinging particular one

Tags: unions

I know the size of union is the size of its largest member. I am not able to deduce how it is represented.
Consider the situation

```
union x
{
    int a;
    char b;
    short int c;
}obj;
   int main()
   {
        obj.a=3;
        printf("%d %c %d",obj.a,obj.b,obj.c);
   }
```

what will be the output and how it will be generated?
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://ideone.com/hbkMfh prog.c:12:12: error: ‘union x’ has no member named ‘x’

Comment: `x` is not a member. Did you mean `obj.a = 3;`? And which language, C, C++, something else? In C you get the `sizeof(type)` bytes with the lowest addresses then, whether those will be the high-order or low-order bytes for `obj.b` and `obj.c` depends on endianness.

Comment: http://ideone.com/IYkQAn  Looks like members are aligned at LSB.

Comment: sorry it was obj.a=3. typo error :(

Answer (score 1):

Your union has no member named x, so assuming you assign a value to one of your members the rest take a portion of that value. For example:

```
union x
{
    long  longval;
    char  charvals[4];
    short shortvals[2];
    char  oneCharVal;
    short oneShortVal;
} obj;

obj.longval = 0x12fe6497;
printf( "c1: %x, c2: %x, c3: %x, c4: %x\n", obj.charvals[0], obj.charvals[1], obj.charvals[2], obj.charvals[3] );
printf( "s1: %x, s2: %x\n", obj.shortvals[0], obj.shortvals[1] );
printf( "oneCharVal: %x\n", obj.oneCharVal );
printf( "oneShortVal: %x\n", obj.oneShortVal );
```

will print:

```
c1: 97, c2: 64, c3: fe, c4: 12
s1: 6497, s2: 12fe
oneCharVal: 97
oneShortVal: 6497
```

I on purpose ignored the sign extend for clarity. %x prints an int, which is usually 32 bits, so it will convert the chars and shorts both to longs before printing and will actually print:

```
c1: ffffff97, c2: 64, c3: fffffffe, c4: 12
s1: 6497, s2: 12fe
oneCharVal: ffffff97
oneShortVal: 6497
```

To print the numbers the way I originally showed you would need to change the printf formatting as follows:

```
printf( "c1: %hhx, c2: %hhx, c3: %hhx, c4: %hhx\n", obj.charvals[0], obj.charvals[1], obj.charvals[2], obj.charvals[3] );
printf( "s1: %hx, s2: %hx\n", obj.shortvals[0], obj.shortvals[1] );
printf( "oneCharVal: %hhx\n", obj.oneCharVal );
printf( "oneShortVal: %hx\n", obj.oneShortVal );
```

I used hex numbers in this example to make it clearer how the numbers are separated because each two digits is one byte (8 bits)

Now this is also very dependant on your processor's endienness. This example is based on little endien, like intel processors. Big endien processors would reverse those numbers.

If you were to assign a value to a member that is smaller than the full union size then the rest of the space is undefined if the instance has never been used before, and will contain the remainder of what was there before if it had been used before. The compiler only writes to the portion of memory that is occupied by the member you are writing to, and masks off the rest so as to not disturb it. The following code:

```
printf( "\n" );
printf( "%x\n", obj.longval );
obj.charvals[2] = 0x193;
printf( "%x\n", obj.longval );
```

yeilds the following result:

```
12fe6497
12936497
```

Notice that instead of writing `0x193`, only `0x93` was written and the rest of the data remains unchanged.

Comment: The last sentence is (possibly) wrong in C. When you write to a member of a union, the bytes not corresponding to the member are indeterminate. It's not unlikely that they retain their previous value, but they could also be overwritten.

Comment: You are correct @DanielFischer. I have updated my answer to reflect this. That said, I use the convert long to array of 4 char all the time and it has always seemed to work in both directions. i.e. if I fill in the array one element at a time, I end up with the correct result. This could, however be a result of the order in which I am filling the array. I will have to test that.

Comment: I did some experiments and found that not not be the case. I also do not believe that to be the case officially, because the compiler knows you are writing to a char so it is supposed to mask off the rest of the data. If I write 0x193 to the second byte, only the 93 portion gets written, as it should. This needs to work this way. It also works this way in bitfields.